# PostForm data to Razor Page Model

Tags: c#, razor-pages

I am trying to post formdata to my razor page via a HTML form.

This is my razor view

```
        <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Test">

            <input type="hidden" name="SlotID" value="wannaPassThis" />

            <div class="row pt-3 justify-content-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-indigo UszPrimaryBg">Registrieren <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

This is the refering razor page model.

```
 public void OnPostTest(string SlotID)
        {

            //Do stuff with slotid

        }
```

I have tried a lot of ways but the onpost doesn't even get executed. So Im struggling to actually access the onpost. I don't really want to use ajax either.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Try some step by step methods:

First, try to fire it up without a handler

```
    <form method="post">

        <input type="hidden" name="SlotID" value="wannaPassThis" />

        <div class="row pt-3 justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-indigo UszPrimaryBg">Registrieren <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Then just a simple Post without even the id

```
    public void OnPost()
    {

        //Do stuff with slotid

    }
```

If this works then try to add the asp without the id too.

```
    public void OnPostTest()
    {
        Message = "Delete handler fired";
    }
```

Let me know how this works. Have you tried with the code in page?

```
@page
@{
    @functions{
        public void OnPostTest(int SlotID)
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this isn't mvc. Im using razor pages. No controller there

Comment: for some reason its calling the get instead of the onpost.

Comment: The empty OnPost? Did you remove the handler from razor?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using asp-page-handler in `<form>` tag, add it into your submit button. Final code will be like below

```
<form method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" name="SlotID" value="wannaPassThis" />
        <div class="row pt-3 justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit" asp-page-handler="Test" class="btn btn-indigo UszPrimaryBg">Registrieren <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: still couldnt find it

Comment: You should also add the OnPostTest() method on the same code behind .cs file.

Comment: yeah have that there still froim the first screenshot